# Can not Update SQL using migration with MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, migration

I have included my screen shots to clarify my question. When I do"Add-migration First" the Identity tables are created after I have done "Update-database" but not my Table from Models. When I look at the Migration file the Table does not get a mention. It appears I feel that I have missed some code somewhere. Any advice greatfully appreciated.

**MODEL**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ICS_Man.Models
{
public class StockPaints
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String PaintCode { get; set; }
}
}
```

**ApplicationDBContext**

```
using ICS_Man.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ICS_Man.Data;

  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{ 
  
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : 
base(options)
   {
   }
    public DbSet<StockPaints> StockPaints { get; set; }

}
```

**Migration File**

```
namespace ICS_Man.Data.Migrations
{
public partial class first : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }
    }
 }
```

Comment: From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio),we just  apply the migrations to initialize the database, we don't need add migration. So try  again, add migration and up database, remember to rename the migration name.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately I did not get a result!!

Comment: Do you see the StockPaints table in SQL Sever?

Comment: No, and that is my problem. The Identity tables are made but not the StockPaints, thanks

Comment: Would like to thank those who answered for your advice. The result is I had not loaded a required package. Thanks